# why does coconut ice turn brown after a couple of days

Tags: coconut

Please can someone help or give advice to solve my problem. I have tried using sorbex but with no advantage

Comment: What is "sorbex"? Google finds it used as a trade name both for at least sorbitol, potassium sorbate, activated carbon and wound bandages.

Comment: What is "coconut ice"? (And I also don't know what "sorbex" is)

Comment: This is one of those cases when giving the recipe that you used would be very helpful.

Comment: I assume that coconut ice is what I found searching for it - a kind of sugar-coconut bar, mostly made in commonwealth countries.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have a fresh fruity thing go brown, the word is "oxidation."

There are a couple of ways to prevent oxidation in sorbet or other fruit ices. The first, and easiest, is to cook your mix before you freeze it. You'll lose some of that "fresh" taste, but your color will be more stable.

The second is to add an acid...Acids love oxygen, and bind it away from your fruit (for a while)...This may not work in your case, since I imagine "Sorbex" is a version of "Fruit Fresh" which is a citric acid powder. Regardless, this will obviously effect the taste.

Finally, you can grind up a chewable vitamin C tablet (or buy powdered Vitamin C) and mix that in.

Comment: The name is misleading: coconut ice isn't frozen. Adding acids probably still works, though.